# array of filters, merge into expression

Tags: php, regex

I have a set of filters defined in a PHP array:

```
$filters = array();
$filters[1] = "STATUS = 'active'";
$filters[2] = "ID != '900'";
$filters[3] = "COUNTRY = 'US'";
//... can be up to 100 filters
```

I also have a user written expression:

```
$filterExp = "1 AND (2 OR 3)";
```

I would like to take the user written expression, and merge in the array of filters to create an output string like the following:

`STATUS = 'active' AND (ID != '900' OR COUNTRY = 'US')`

Would anyone please help me out with a regular expression for this in PHP?  I've fought with it for too long and now must ask for help.
Edit:
Been struggling with something like `preg_replace('(\d+)', '$filters["$1"]', $filterExp);` but I know I'm missing something...

`$filtersQuery = preg_replace_callback(
        '(\d+)', function ($matches) use ($filters) {
    return $filters[$matches[0]];
}, $filterExp
);`

Comment: ... what have you tried?

Comment: This is called [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Computer_languages) and cannot be done with regular expressions.

Comment: Now your preg_replace_callback already produces the desired output or not? (Btw, if you just substitute only a few expressions always in order, `%s` and `sprintf` might be another option.)

Comment: your code already produces the desired output

Comment: If I have a filter count >10 my numbers get mixed up

Comment: show us an example crashing your code

Comment: I can confirm that your code works. Check the inputs if you don't get the correct results.

Comment: https://eval.in/177912

Comment: it will be easier to substitute the 'predefined filters' if you enable them to be easily identified in the 'target' string by surrounding them with characters to make them into easily identified 'tokens'. i.e. instead of "1 AND (2 OR 3)" use: "%1% AND (%2% OR %3%)"

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `preg_replace_callback`, you have a faster way (from far) using `strtr`:

```
$filtersQuery = strtr($filterExp, $filters);
```